# unable to parse ansible variable in jinja file using if condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm encountering below error while trying to pass ansible variable through if condition in jinja. (elsewhere I'm able to pass a string direclty and use the same condition in jinja and also able to read the ansible variable without any condition) Any leads please...

**yaml extract**

```
---
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ansible_role: "role1"

    - name: Create the Jinja2 based template
      template: src=./source.j2 dest=./output.txt
```

**source.j2**

```
---
{% for role in roles %}
{% if {{ ansible_role }} == role.name %}
{% for item in role.tests %}
"{{ item }}"
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**error**

> ```
> TASK [Create the Jinja2 based template] 
> ***************************************
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token
>  ':', got '}'. String: ---\n{% for role in roles %}\n{% if {{
>  ansible_role }} == role.name %}\n{% for item in role.tests
>  %}\ninclude_controls \"{{ item }}\"\n{% endfor %}\n{% endif %}\n{%
>  endfor %}\n"}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some time to review the [jinja2 template designer documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/). Your variable name is already inside a jinja2 expression. The double curly braces has to be used outside expressions to have the content of your variable written out, not inside an expression.

Therefore, you should change:

```
# !! WRONG !!
{% if {{ ansible_role }} == role.name %}
```

to

```
{% if ansible_role == role.name %}
```

My last 2 cent: don't prepend your own variable names with `ansible_` as this is used by ansible itself for a lot of internal/magic variables and might lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line: `{% if {{ ansible_role }} == role.name %}`. When you use the `{%  %}` notation, Jinja expects python inside. So you don't need to escape the `ansible_role` variable. Try it without it and see if now it works.